# angularjs date format validation on input type date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I'm trying to create date using AngularJS and as per the documentation

> Input with date validation and transformation. In browsers that do not
>   yet support the HTML5 date input, a text element will be used. In that
>   case, text must be entered in a valid ISO-8601 date format
>   (yyyy-MM-dd), for example: 2009-01-06. Since many modern browsers do
>   not yet support this input type, it is important to provide cues to
>   users on the expected input format via a placeholder or label.

it only accepts valid ISO-8601 date format (yyyy-MM-dd).

I've tried to define the new date format in the `pattern`'s attribute as shown in the following code:

```
<div ng-app="">
  <form name="frmSPA" novalidate>
    <input type="date" placeholder="Enter SPA Date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" name="SPADate" ng-model="SPADate" ng-required="true" />
    <span ng-show="frmSPA.SPADate.$touched && frmSPA.SPADate.$error.required">SPA Date is required</span>
    <span ng-show="frmSPA.SPADate.$touched && frmSPA.SPADate.$error.date">Not a valid date</span>
  </form>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work.

So how to change the default date format into `dd/MM/yyyy`. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8b3dxbn/).

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: @RayonDabre I think the link given is about how to format the date display, but I need the textbox to accept `dd/MM/yyyy` format

Comment: I guess it depends on the format of your system date...Not sure...

Comment: @RayonDabre I'm using `dd/MM/yyyy` format on my system date

Comment: Have you considered using [ui-bootstrap's datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) ? It has everything you want and more

Comment: Ok, I will consider it, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should write an *ad hoc* directive, to be really cross-browser compatible...
Something like this:

```
angular
    .module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, dateFilter) {
        $scope.date = new Date();
    })
    .directive(
        'dateInput',
        function(dateFilter) {
            return {
                require: 'ngModel',
                template: '<input type="date"></input>',
                replace: true,
                link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
                        return dateFilter(modelValue, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
                    });

                    ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                        return new Date(viewValue);
                    });
                },
            };
    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/Vq65z/14/)

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-pattern instead of pattern.
Also use a regular expression instead of a date format to validate the date correctly.

ng-pattern='/(([0-2]?\d{1})|([3][0,1]{1}))/^[0,1]?\d{1}/(([1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1})|([2-9]{1}\d{3}))$/'

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this ng-pattern also working for leap year. Work for 'MM-dd-YYYY' format.

ng-pattern='/^(((0[13578]|1[02])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[13456789]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(02-(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(02-29-((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/'