# angularjs how to work validation on date . when I use date pickers

Tags: jquery, angularjs, validation, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I don't know how to set the Scheduled Date field is required. I didn't get the data when it set as required.Please help, if anyone knows about it. Validation not working.

view:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Scheduled Date</label>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="dt">
    <input class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium default-date-picker" name="date" ng-model="set_date" type="text" required/>
  </div>
  <div ng-messages="myForm.date.$error" style="color:maroon">
    <p ng-message="required"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> No.of Trucks required.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-10">
    <button type="submit" ng-click="post_load()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs date format validation on input type date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306128/angularjs-date-format-validation-on-input-type-date)

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. I just need date validation when I'm using date pickers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use angular validation ways, change `required` to `ng-required="true"`.

Comment: how it possible. i didn't get the data